# Use JQuery to find XSL xpath value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I'm having some issues coming up with a solution to the following problem.

The following code creates a drop down menu based on the xpath @label attribute.

```
    <select name="endYear" id="endYear" class="validate[required]">
       <xsl:for-each select="/campusRoot/yearList/yearList">
        <option value="{@endYear}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
        </option>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </select>
```

I would like to dynamically find the registration type based on the distinct label that's selected in the drop down menu?  Below is the XML:

```
    <yearList>
      <yearList olr_yearID="1" endYear="2012" label="11-12"  active="false" registrationType=""/>
      <yearList olr_yearID="2" endYear="2013" label="12-13" active="false" registrationType="Immediate"/>
      <yearList olr_yearID="10" endYear="2015" label="14-15 Summer Academy" active="true" registrationType="Summer Academy"/>
      <yearList olr_yearID="13" endYear="2014" label="13-14 Summer Academy" active="true" registrationType="Summer Academy"/>
    </yearList>
```

I would then like to pass this value as a hidden input.

FYI...The endYear isn't always distinct; i.e. there are multiple registrationTypes per endYear.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one working solution to my original question:

In head put:

```
var yearList = [];
<xsl:for-each select="/campusRoot/yearList/yearList">
  yearList['<xsl:value-of select="@olr_yearID"/>'] = {registrationType: '<xsl:value-of select="@registrationType"/>', endYear: '<xsl:value-of select="@endYear"/>'}
</xsl:for-each>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    registration();

    $('#reglabel').change(function() {
      registration();
    });

    function registration() {
      var result = yearList[$('#reglabel').val()].registrationType;
      var result2 = yearList[$('#reglabel').val()].endYear;
      document.getElementById('registrationType').value = result;
      document.getElementById('endYear').value = result2;
    }
  });
```

In the body put:

```
<select name="reglabel" id="reglabel" class="reglabel" >
  <xsl:for-each select="/campusRoot/yearList/yearList">
    <option value="{@olr_yearID}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>   
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Note:  The olr_yearID is distinct which is necessary to find the correct attributes. To implement this answer you must import JQuery library.  The document.getElementById is referring to a hidden input that is being submitted with other parameters.

Also, there is another way to do this with AJAX which dynamically generates the XML, but since I already needed to load the XML for other purposes this was probably the most efficient solution for me to implement.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider doing something like:

```
<select name="endYear" id="endYear" class="validate[required]">
   <xsl:for-each select="/campusRoot/yearList/yearList">
    <option value="{@endYear}" data-id="{@olr_yearID}" data-active="{@active}" data-type="{@registrationType}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
    </option>
   </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

and then doing:

```
$('#endYear').change(function() {
    alert($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-type'));
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The alert would print an empty string.

Comment: How about:
    $('#endYear').change(function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });